# Biholomorphic mapping of a quarter-disk to the upper half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, linear-fractional-transformation

Can you verify this solution?

The question asks for a biholomorphic mapping of the domain $D=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1, \text{Re}(z) > 0, \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$ to the upper half-plane $P=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \text{Im}(z) > 0\}$.

I first attempted to map the quarter-disk to the half-plane by mapping the circular arc of the quarter-disk to the line through the real axis by the transformation $$T_{1}(z) = \frac{z-i}{z} \cdot \frac{1}{1-i} = \dfrac{(1+i)z + (1-i)}{2z},$$ but this mapped it to the lower half-plane, so I multiplied by $e^{i \pi} = -1$ to rotate it to the upper half-plane, resulting in the map $$T(z) = \dfrac{(1+i)z + (1-i)}{-2z}.$$

That is, $T$ should map $D$ to $P$.

Is this correct? I found this question in a qualifying exam for a different school than mine, but there is no attached answer key.

Comment: It is $e^{i \pi}=-1$

Comment: I don't think it is a right reasoning and a right result. I would advise you to take these two steps : 1) $z \to z^4=u$ to transform the quarter-disk into the full disk, then 2) $u \to \frac{u-1}{u+1}=v$ for the transformation of the whole disk into the upper half plane.

Comment: @JeanMarie That seems natural, but isn't the image of your first map is missing $[0,1) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$? Also, there is an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360297/biholomorphic-transformation-from-half-disk-onto-full-one?rq=1

Comment: @JeanMarie In response to your first comment, that is correct, it was an error on my part which I have fixed - none of the following calculations change.

In response to your second comment, what exactly is the error in my solution? I believe (perhaps incorrectly) that this problem should be solvable with Möbius transforms, which (if true) means it should be possible to solve this question without fourth powers.

Comment: @legionwhale Thanks for the response and the URL you attached - in fact, as I reread the post you attached and Jean Marie's responses, I am beginning to believe that my solution is ill-fated - I don't think it's possible to solve with ONLY Möbius transforms, as I attempted to do (It's been a while since I took complex analysis...)

Comment: @Legionwhale You are right : I missed that...

Comment: @cluxo98 A single Möbius transformation cannot be the answer. Indeed, one of the properties of a Möbius transformation is that it preserves angles : but where the $\pi/2$ angle of the quarter circle would be mapped onto ?

Comment: Okay, after some tinkering, I think I've got it.

We take the quarter-disk to the upper half unit disk by $z^{2}$. Then we take the half-disk to the left half-plane with $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$. Then we just need to rotate by $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, which corresponds to multiplying by $-i$. All together, the transformation looks like $T(z) = \frac{1-z^{2}}{z^{2}+1}$. I appreciate your help @JeanMarie, I will mark this as an answer for other people to see.

Comment: I forgot to multiply the $i$ properly in my above comment; the final result should be $T(z) = \frac{i - iz^{2}}{z^{2} + 1}.$